# AWS Eventbridge not sending messages towards SQS when encrypted with SSE-KMS (CMK)

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

My flow is:

- Secret Change Manager triggers an event (eg. someone is changing a secret value)
- Eventbridge rule target is a SNS topic which informs via email different recipients.
- In case of failure to reach SNS, unprocessed events are sent to a DLQ in Amazon SQS

Now, this works fine when my SQS queue is encrypted with SSE-SQS or unencrypted.
But when I use SSE-KMS (either with CMK or aws default one) no messages arrive into my SQS, even though SNS is not reachable.

I'm thinking the issue must be inside the Access Policy somewhere,but I have tried giving the most amount of access, and still without success.

Part of the policy is below:

```
{
"Sid": "example-statement-ID",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
  "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
},
"Action": [
  "kms:GenerateDataKey",
  "kms:DescribeKey",
  "kms:Encrypt",
  "kms:ReEncrypt",
  "kms:Decrypt"
],
"Resource": "*"
},
```

Did anyone had a similar flow and managed to make it work using SSE-KMS ?
Any advice is greatly appreciated since I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, in my case it was due to KMS Key Policy, Eventbridge did not have the right permissions to the KMS key.
After adding :

```
    {
      "Sid": "example-statement-ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "kms:Decrypt"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
```

It seems it works properly now.